# PCF (Pivotal CLoud Foundry ) is appending content lenght to my applictaion

Tags: java, rest, pcfdev

The logs below are from PCF:

```
[APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] },
{Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Date=[Thu, 11 Oct 2018 01:17:46 GMT], X-Application-Context=[sg-payment-gateway-service:dev,cloud:0], 
X-Newrelic-App-Data=[PxQGVlVUDwMFR1BXBgAEX1YADhFORDQHUjZKA1ZLVVFHDFYPbU5gEhZfWQYlDFZHQgsNDlJDa0ktX19HIxYKIV8MTBBXVFhXQTkWCF8IRzIFT1oECBcaHwBKUU4HHwdVVAIPA1VKVVIcQAlQCgFVVwADDVUAWQMAUlQVTQACVEBVOQ==], 
X-Vcap-Request-Id=[dce381ea-c25d-423f-5dfb-2e7275f7ec69], **Content-Length=[700],** Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000;]}>
```

When I deploy my application in PCF, this content length is getting appended shortening my response. The same in my local works. How to set content length in PCF?

Comment: Can you provide code examples? I can't understand anything you have said.

Comment: I have a REST API which is sending a set of parameters to my other API, this code works in my local, when i push it to PCF my response is getting appended to 700 characters and PCF logs add content length.

Comment: My question is how do we set content lenght in PCF or how do we avoid PCF doing the same